# Some keyboard keys not working in terminal

Tags: keyboard

I use my Raspberry Pi via SSH and
the 'f' and 'b' keys do not work in the terminal (the 'F' and 'B' do work, though).
Also, when I start a text editor vim/vi/nano, every key works. It seems to be a problem with the terminal itself. Does anyone know how I could fix this?

This is the output of `uname -a`:

```
Linux raspberrypi 4.4.15-v7+ #897 SMP Tue Jul 12 18:42:55 BST 2016 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Are the keys bound to a command? What happens when you type the keys twice?

Comment: Keys are not bound to a command and nothing happens if I type the keys twice or more.

Comment: I wonder if your system has `xev` installed (http://linux.die.net/man/1/xev). Start it and try the keys again.

Comment: The problem seems to be gone though I'm not really sure what was the cause (Might have happened when I connected my Ardnuino to it... really don't know). I'll send feedback if it happens again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out years later, with a similar mistake, that the problem was due to a bad configuration of my `.inputrc` file.

The configuration was something like that : 

`bind '"\e[A": history-search-backward'
bind '"\e[B": history-search-forward'`

There are two possible situation that could have happened :

- I executed `. .inputrc` and forgot the ''
- This bad configuration of the `.inputrc` was executed at login

For the second case not to cause an error, the syntax should have been : 

`"\e[A": history-search-backward
"\e[B": history-search-forward`

The solution is to reset the key bindings with first :

  `set -o vi`

to reset the binding for the 'b' and 'f' keys then 

  `set -o emacs`

to recover the nice EMACS bindings.
Strangely I found out that `set -o emacs` alone would not reset the bad bindings.

Answer (score 1):

Kind of weird. You might try `raspi-config` -- under *Internationalization Options* there is a means of setting the keyboard type.

Beware I think initially (or if after you choose "English"?) it shows only shows a variety of UK style layouts, none of which correspond to US ones; to see those you have to choose "other" first.

Most people on the west side of the Atlantic have a US style 104 key PC keyboard.  You have to reboot for this to take effect (or you could try plugging and unplugging the keyboard, but I think a reboot is needed).

Comment: It tried to change keyboard layout and got this error after selecting to option _change keyborad layout_ : _update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults_

Comment: Don't worry about that; it has to do with backward compatibility with the [init system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Init) used in the first version of Raspbian.  The keyboard setup should still work (although I noticed the last installs I did the boot process may hang on that for <= 90s the first time or so) -- but I can't promise it will fix your particular problem.